# Can anyone tell me why 8>7<6 = true?

Tags: javascript, jquery, console.log

Can anyone tell me why

```
8>7<6 = true
12>10>2 = false
```

Please give answer 
[image]

Please Go through the image also

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In an MCQ interview they are asking these kind of stupid Question , they had given true false and error options Only

Comment: `8>7` is `true` and `true < 6` is `true` so `(8>7)<6 = true`. `12>10` is `true` and `true>2` is `false` so `(12>10)>2 = false`

Comment: I'm sorry for the messy comments guys.

Comment: It's a common misconception that there is a direct link between classical maths, & computer maths when it comes to writing them down,.  The above in computer maths would be `8>6 && 7<6`   and `12>10 && 10>2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers are saying, it will be evaluated from left to right so:

```
8 > 7 // true
true < 6 // true
```

But if you want the statement to read more mathematically logically you would need to split up the comparisons like:

```
8 > 7 && 7 < 6 //false
```

Comment: Nice focus on the OP deep question. ;)

Comment: @JohnR that works exactly the same. `12>10` is true, `true > 2` is false, so the end result is false

Answer (score 8):

Here `true = 1` and `false =0` and expression evaluate from left to right

1) 8>7<6 = true

```
8>7 = true
true<6 = 1<6=true
```

2) 12>10>2 = false

```
12>10=true
  true>2 = 1>2= false
```

Comment: 8 is greater than 7 right?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette what is your problem with `8>7`?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette what do you think it should be `8>7`?

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette it's obviously being explicit as to show how the logic flows.

Answer (score 6):

In javascript the comaprison expression is evaluated from leftmost to right so

When you do `8 > 7 < 6`, it undergoes the steps:

```
8 > 7 //true
true < 6 // true, since boolean value true is 1
```

Similarly when you do `12 > 10 >2`, it undergoes the steps:

```
12 > 10 //true
true > 2 //false, since boolean value true is 1
```

Furthermore, you cannot assume that `12 > 10 > 2` will evaluate as a whole.

Comment: @freedomn-m that is left to right

Comment: @freedomn-m ok maybe the word `rightmost ` is suitable for this.

Comment: Thanks @ankit Agarwal  this really make sense :)

Comment: @Rahul glad to help you

Comment: @freedomn-m Comparisons are made left to right one by one. As soon as it encounters a false... that's the end of the condition "as a whole".

Comment: @freedomn-m oh i got what you were saying. My bad, I was thinking other side. You are correct it is `leftmost to right`. Thanks

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Yes he was right. It was my typo in the answer

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette: Not in comparisons. Only (some) logical conditions short-circuit at a `false`.

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal: I also messed the logic loll.. Don't worry. ;) **Hey! That was a good question after all!**

Comment: Few - glad I wasn't going mad :)  Conversely some operations *are* right-to-left, eg assignment `var a = b = c = 1;` == `var a = (b = (c = 1))`

Comment: removed my comments as they no longer add anything